# Is it possible to replace battery in an old iPad?

Tags: ipad, battery

I have an old iPad 2.  The battery goes dead when it is unused for only one day. Should I change the battery and if yes, how should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, but it's incredible hard for almost any average or advanced user, so I highly recommend against it, sorry.

[Here is a nice step by step guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPad+2+Wi-Fi+EMC+2415+Battery+Replacement/5383) from the folks of iFixit, if you are (really) adventurous enough...

Best luck!

Comment: Actually I had this done recently at a local phone repair shop. Many of them will be able to replace batteries, glass and screens for a reasonable cost. Doing it yourself with no previous experience, unless you do a lot of electronics repair, could easily result in a pile of useless junk.